# Binding Image element to a property in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I have an image element in xaml and I want to bind it with a property in my view model. I have a binding of xaml Image element to a property called MainImage as shown below.

```
private Image mainImage_ = new Image();
    public Image MainImage
    {
        get
        {
            return mainImage_;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mainImage_ != value)
            {
                mainImage_ = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MainImage");
            }                                        
        }
    }
```

I want to set the image to an image element in xaml, by browsing it from the computer and I have done it like this way.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
            MainImage = bitmapImage;                    
            new MainPage().DataContext = file;                             
        }
```

MainImage = bitmapImage is showing an error that we can't set it directly. 
How can I resolve it? 
Should the return type of property be a string (a path) or an Image? 
If there is an other better way to do, then let me know please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model property should be of type `ImageSource`, not `Image`:

```
private ImageSource mainImage;
public ImageSource MainImage
{
    get { return mainImage; }
    set
    {
        if (mainImage != value)
        {
            mainImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainImage");
        }                                        
    }
}
```

Now you could bind the Source property of an `Image` control in XAML to your view model like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MainImage}"/>
```

However, this requires that the DataContext of your Page is set to an instance of your view model, e.g. like

```
DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

You should not set it to something else later, as you seem to be doing in the line

```
new MainPage().DataContext = file;
```

Besides that, it's unclear why you create a new MainPage instance in that line.

Comment: Thank alot, it worked. however I have set the data context directly in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the source property of the Image to your bitmap. Try:

```
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(img.BaseUri,file.Name);
            MainImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see the UWP, try this.

Comment: It throws NullReferenceException.

Comment: Are you sure MainImage is getting initialized?

Comment: The code given above, is all I have written for this purpose.